# Fitting GLM with Quasi-Newton method

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to code my own quasi-Newton algorithm for fitting GLMs in R. My results do not match up with `glm` and I've been over my code many, many times so I'm wondering if I have the math wrong.

My understanding is that the $\beta$ vector is updated in the following way:
$$
\beta^{(t+1)} = \beta^{(t)} + \left[-S'(\beta^{(t)})\right]^{-1} \times S(\beta^{(t)}) 
$$

where $S$ is the score function. Because I'm doing quasi-Newton I will replace the $\left[-S(\beta^{(t)})\right]^{-1}$ with an estimate denoted by $V_t$, which is a function of the score function evaluated at $\beta^{(t)}$ and $\beta^{(t-1)}$.

Therefore my actual procedure is 
$$
\beta^{(t+1)} = \beta^{(t)} + V_t \times S(\beta^{(t)}). 
$$

If $Y_1, \dots, Y_n \sim \ iid \  f(y | \theta, \phi)$ where $f$ is an exponential family, $\theta$ is the canonical parameter, $\phi$ is the dispersion parameter, and $l$ is the log-likelihood, then we have

$$
\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta_j}(\beta_j|\vec{y}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i - \mu_i}{a_i \nu(\mu_i)} \times \frac{d\mu_i}{d\eta_i} \times x_{i,j}
$$

where $a_i = a_i(\phi) / \phi$, $\eta_i = x_{(i)}^T\beta \ $  [$x_{(i)}$ is the $i$th row of $X$], and $g(\mu_i) = \eta_i$ for link function $g$. From this we have that $\frac{d\mu_i}{d\eta_i} = \frac{1}{g'(\eta_i)}$.

[source](http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/21121_Chapter_15.pdf): page 26.

I wrote a function to compute a vector `score` according to the above formula, taking as inputs all the things typically passed to `glm` such as `x`, `y`, `g`, `g.prime`, `g.inv`, `a.vec`, `v.func`, and initial values `beta1`, `beta2`.

I iterate the following until convergence:

1. compute $S(\beta^{(t)})$ and $S(\beta^{(t-1)})$
2. update $V_t$ using those two vectors
3. compute  $\beta^{(t+1)}$ according to the above formula

The problem is that my $V_t$ and $\beta$ blow up leading to divisions by 0 and lots of `NaN`s. What am I missing? Is there a problem with the math or do I just have a bug that I missed? Thanks very much for any comments/suggestions.

Comment: Post your code and a sample dataset....

Comment: I deliberately didn't post my code because I didn't want to make this about code review. I just want to know if the math and overall procedure that I'm using is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In honor of it having been exactly two years since I asked this, I figured I'll post an answer now.

For some differentiable function $f : \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$, Newton's method seeks a stationary point by iterating
$$
x^{(i+1)} = x^{(i)} - H^{-1}(x^{(i)}) \nabla f(x^{(i)})
$$
which is just an application of Newton's method for root finding to the derivative of $f$.

Computing $H^{-1}$ at every point can be a major pain for any sizable $p$, so we can use a [Quasi-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method) method whereby we approximate it with a matrix $V^{(i)}$ that is a function of $x^{(i)}$ and $x^{(i-1)}$.

It turns out the formula that I was using to compute my particular $V^{(i)}$ was just wrong. The approach I describe in the question is indeed correct.